# Conditional row number Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to add row number to my dataframe based on certain condition, below is the image input data frame.

[image]

I need a row number column in my dataframe as illustrated in below image(Rank column).

[image]

so when ever "RequestResubmitted" value is found within group I want reset rank to 1 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `cumsum` create the cub key and `groupby` + `cumcount`

```
s=df.groupby([df['Word Order Code'],df['Status Code'].eq('Request Submitted').cumsum()]).cumcount()+1
df['rank']=s
```